# Strings to excel

Tags: java, android

I'm really new to programming. I'm creating a program that generates some strings. I would like to implement the option of exporting said strings to an excel file. I have searched on google but to no avail. What would be my best option?

Comment: Look into importing CSV

Comment: you can consult to this link http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/